# Nestjs middleware with dependencies

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am having trouble creating a middleware that has two dependencies (TypeORModule.forFeature([USER]), FirebaseModule).
What I have done is create an AuthModule which looks like this:

```
    @Module({
    imports: [
        FirebaseModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthMiddleware
    ],
})
```

and the middleware which looks like this

```
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService
) {}

async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {...}    
}
```

and my app module which looks like this

```
@Module({
imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        ...config.get("database"),
        entities: [__dirname + '/entities/**/*.{js,ts}']
    }),
    AuthModule,
    exampleModule
],
providers: [
    AuthMiddleware
]
})

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): any {
        consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes("*")
    }
}
```

I get many errors and I try to shift things around to make it work but I simply can't get it to happen. I get errors from

Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [0] is available in the module(sometimes AppModule, sometimes exampleModule) context.

Do other modules (controller ones, as in providing api services) need to also import the middleware module if it applies to them too?

In general, how do I go on about implementing middlewares that depend on external modules? Do they have to be modules so I can import the requires modules?

I'd love some help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shiouldn't need to re-add `AuthMiddleware` to the `AppModule`'s `providers`. It already exists in `AuthModule`. Also, you can bind the middleware inside the `AuthModule` if you want instead of in the `AppModule` and it will have the same global scope.